# Passing exception from anonymous interface to a method signature

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, interface

I'm running into a situation where i need to pass an exception from an anonymous interface defined inside a method body to the method definition. I'm not sure if this is the proper way to describe my problem but I will try to explain through the coding.

So this is the example of the code

```
public interface OnCompletedListener{
    void onCompleted(Object result);
}

public class Networking{

    public void fetchData(OnCompletedListener onCompletedListener){
        // Fetching data
    }

    public List<Data> populateDataList(){
        List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList();
        fetchData(new OnCompletedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Object result){
                if(result == null) throw new Exception("exception");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

So, My aim here is to add the Exception to the populateDataList() method signature. because i can just add it to the anonymous interface onCompleted() method signature. So is there any way i can use to pass the exception to the method signature to be like this.

```
public List<Data> populateDataList() throws Exception{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current implementation it depends on `fetchData` if `populateDataList` throws an exception. If you do `try-catch` around `onCompletedListener.onCompleted` then you should not declare it. If you want to propagate to `populateDataList` then you can do as follows:

First you can add `throws Exception` to `onCompleted` in the implementation and in the interface. When you implement `fetchData` and call `onCompletedListener.onCompleted`, then you must declare `fetchData` to throw `Exception`. And finally you must declare `populateDataList` to throw `Exception`. Your code will look like

```
public interface OnCompletedListener {
  void onCompleted(Object result) throws Exception;
}

public class Networking{

  public void fetchData(OnCompletedListener onCompletedListener) throws Exception {
    onCompletedListener.onCompleted(null);
  }

  public List<Data> populateDataList() throws Exception {
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    fetchData(new OnCompletedListener(){
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(Object result) throws Exception{
        if(result == null) throw new Exception("exception");
      }
    });
    return dataList;
  }

}
```

Remarks:

- it is good practice to use specific exceptions and avoid throwing generic exceptions like `Exception`
- if you work with java 8+ then you can replace your anonymous inner class with a lambda
- you should instantiate a generic `ArrayList`, i.e. `new ArrayList<>()`

Answer (score 1):

I noticed some conflicts in your code such as instantiating a generic arraylist `new ArrayList<>()`, so hopefully these changes may solve your problems.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Networking{

    public List<String> populateDataList(){
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();            
        fetchData(new OnCompletedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Object result){
                if(result == null) new Exception("exception");
            }
        });
    return dataList;
    }

    public void fetchData(OnCompletedListener onCompletedListener){
        // Fetching data
    }



}


interface OnCompletedListener{
    void onCompleted(Object result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This code should run.

import java.util.*;

public class Networking{

    public List<String> populateDataList(){
    List<Data> dataList = new java.util.ArrayList<Data>();            
        fetchData(new OnCompletedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Object result){
                if(result == null) new Exception("exception");
            }
        });
    return dataList;
    }

    public void fetchData(OnCompletedListener onCompletedListener){
        // Fetching data
    }



}


interface OnCompletedListener{
    void onCompleted(Object result);
}
```